# Vaadin init method execution

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm new to Vaadin and i'm trying to understand its complicated architecture read in vaadin book.
I wanted to verify its time responce with different browsers (IE11 and Chrome)

so i wrote this little application (vaadin tutorial address book):

```
public class MyVaadinUI extends Application implements Button.ClickListener, Property.ValueChangeListener, ItemClickEvent.ItemClickListener {

//-----------------------------------------------------
// IMPLEMENTATIONS
//-----------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void init() {
    System.out.println("Calling init() method...");
    long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    buildMainLayout();
    // get the execution time from start to end
    System.out.println("took time-->" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime));
}
```

Here's the result log:

```
Calling init() method...
took time-->2
Calling init() method...
took time-->2
Calling init() method...
took time-->4
```

I can't understand why the init method is executed 3 times.

Kind regards

Comment: It gets called every time a new request is made. Did you open the page with different browsers? Also, the time response to build the UI is independent of the browser.

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna From the first request i get the log above. I have to write a report about time response problem of vaadin6 with IE11 this is why i have to print took time lines. Thank you

Comment: What kind of request do you send? Do you just open the URL in webbrowser? Or do you click on a button or something similar?

Comment: its' the URL opened in the browser